# Running two batch files from one file doesn't always work

Tags: windows, batch-file, android-emulator

When I run this batch file then the ADB is not always connect
the emulator, so I have to start this file again to make it work.

```
:: starts Blue Stacks first
call bstacks.bat

:: this starts Android Debug Bridge
cd C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
call connect.bat
```

where first file

```
start "HDPlayer" "%ProgramFiles%\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe"
```

and second file

```
adb connect localhost:5555
```

How to fix it? I need to run the emulator and then connect it to localhost.

Comment: BTW you can replace `C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local` with `%LocalAppData%`.

Comment: maybe a `timeout /t 5 >nul` helps to give the HD-Player enough time to actually start before you try to connect to it? (Adapt the 5 seconds to a better fit, when you know, how long the EXE will need to start)

Comment: @Stephan need to test, if I use `timeout /t 8 /nobreak >nul` it displays in cmd-window as `timeout /t 8 /nobreak 1>nul`. what is the `1` there?

Comment: `1` is the stream number. Stream 1 is STDOUT (Standard Output), Stream 2 is STDERR (Standard Error Output). `>` is just an abbreviation for the default of `1>`, so if you just use `>`, the parser corrects it to the correct `1>`